# Animation doesn't start after reopening the app?

Tags: animation, swift

**Objective**

I need my app to scale a `UIImage`.

**Code**

To do so, I use this method:

```
func animateStuff() {

    println("Animate stuff called!")

    let optionsAnimateStuff = UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction
    let value : CGFloat = 1.045

               UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9, delay: 0.0, options:
                optionsAnimateStuff, animations: {

                    println("Let's scale this image!")

                self.image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(value, value)

            }, completion: { finished in })
}
```

When I close the app and open it again the method gets called again (due to the code inside `applicationDidBecomeActive`but the `UIImage` does not animate anymore.

**Question**

Why doesn't the object animate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that the image still has the previous transform applied.  You likely want to return it to its original when the animation completes (when the view goes away).

Try using this code in your `completion`:

```
{ finished in
    self.image.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
}
```